# Condition on many-to-many does not fetch all right data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I have an issue with many-to-many conditions.
I have this kind of data:

```java
class Todo {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

I am trying to find Todo from some attachment ids like this:

```java
interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, String> {
  @Query("select t from Todo t left join fetch t.attachments attachment where attachment.id in (:attachmentIds)")
  List<Todo> findAttachedTodos(List<String> attachmentIds);
}
```

I am able to retrieve the corresponding todos.
If a Todo has multiple attachments I can't retrieve the ones which are not in attachmentIds in the result Todo.
If I remove the condition I am able to retrieve all attachments.

How can I retrieve all attachments?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you represent the connection between the "Todo" and "Attachment" in your database? (If it is stored id DB)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
There is a join table which stores the attachment id (1st column) and todo id (2nd column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an exists subquery:

```
interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, String> {
  @Query("select t from Todo t left join fetch t.attachments attachment where exists (select 1 from t.attachments a where a.id in (:attachmentIds))")
  List<Todo> findAttachedTodos(List<String> attachmentIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to use a join table if you have one. If i would bet it could be a possible solution. You should replace the names with you database columns tables and other variables.

```
@Entity
public class Todo { 
    // ...
 
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "todo_attachment", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "todo_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id") }
    )
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
   
}
```

And your attachment entity should looks like something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Attachment {    
    // ...  
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "attachments")
    private List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();
     
}
```

Further [reading](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) about introduction to many to many connection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it’s not working.
The many-to-many was already working.
My issue is about the condition which filters the attachments of the Todo.